# Introducing variables to Gson

Tags: android, json, variables, deserialization, gson

I have a large JSON file that contains A LOT of similar code. It's similar to this:

```
...,"techs":{"t1":{"level":24,"able":true},"t2":{"level":23,"able":true},"t3":{"level":20,"able":true},"t4"...,"t5"...
```

It has since **t1** until **t510**... For this reason, I have to create an activity for each **tN**, so I have to create 510 activities! 0.0

To get acces to each **tN** I use the following lines:

```
       Gson gson = new Gson();
        Planets json = gson.fromJson(str, Planets.class);

        System.out.println(json.techs.t1.level);
        System.out.println(json.techs.t2.level);
                         etc...
```

So I wanna know if there's the possibility to change **t1** for a variable, so that I only have to change the variable to access **t2** in a single activity.

For example: `String tech = t456; System.out.println(json.techs.tech.level);`

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It's all just about your imagination ;-)*

I will come out from this JSON snippet

```
"techs":{"t1":{"level":24,"able":true},"t2":{"level":23,"able":true},"t3":{"level":20,"able":true}}
```

This is easily representable as this structure

```
HashMap<String, InnerObject>
```

where `InnerObject` class is defined like this:

```
class InnerObject {
    int level;
    boolean able;
}
```

So everything you need is class, where single field will be called `techs` and it will be defined like this:

```
class JSONWrapper {
    // another variables
    HashMap<String, InnerObject> techs;
}
```

To access fields after, you can use:

```
String techId = "t546";
InnerObject = JSONWrapperInstance.techs.get(techId);
```

Whole code:

```
String str = "... contains JSON string ...";
JSONWrapper JSONWrapperInstance = new Gson().fromJson(str, JSONWrapper.class);
```

And you can walk through all items in `HashMap` like this:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = JSONWrapperInstance.techs.keySet().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    InnerObject = JSONWrapperInstance.techs.get(iterator.next());
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for your excellent reply! Tomorrow morning I'll try this out! It seems that it will work without problems. Tomorrow I'll vote your response. Thank you!

Comment: I'm trying to acces the data but is the log shows: pac.ka.ge.Overview$InnerObject@b5e92010 At least it doesn't throw error! EDITED: Fix it! I just had to change type of InnerObject to int! Thank you very much! It works like a charm! :D

Comment: I'm having problems... I'm always getting NullPointerException! Galax galax = new Gson().fromJson(strGalaxy, Galax.class); double er = galax.pos.get("p2").debris.titanium; strGalaxy is OK, and the classes are OK too, I think everything is correct... public class Galax  {
  
        public HashMap <String, InnerObject> pos;
    }public class InnerObject {
     public Debris debris;
 }
    
    public class Debris {
     
     public double titanium;
    } JSON snippet: {"p1":{"debris":{"titanium":0,"silicum":0}},"p2":{"debris":{"titanium":0,"silicum":0}}

Comment: @KrLx_roller start new question, now when you know how to (de)serialize with Gson, problem can be placed somewhere else.

Comment: New question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963464/nullpointerexception-deserializing-with-gson