# NullPointerException deserializing with gson

Tags: android, json, variables, serialization, gson

I have a JSON that contains the following:

```
{"p1":{"debris":{"titanium":0,"silicum":0}},"p2":{"debris":{"titanium":0,"silicum":0}}...
```

I declare the data using HashMap:

```
public class Galax  {

    public HashMap <String, InnerObject> pos;
}

public class InnerObject {

    public Debris debris;
}

public class Debris {

    public double titanium, silicum;
}
```

And I call the data using this:

```
        Galax galax = new Gson().fromJson(strGalaxy, Galax.class);
        System.out.println(galax.pos.get("p2").debris.titanium);
```

The problem is that I **always** get NullPointerException when trying to show the data in the log... I do not understand why, because I use do it exactly the same way to get data of other JSON and it works perfectly...

What can be the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you  could post the entire stacktrace you're more likely to get a helpful answer.

Comment: You say you're hitting a nullpointer at this line: "System.out.println(galax.pos.get("p2").debris.titanium);" well try to run it through the debugger and see exactly what point you hit the null pointer at. It could be "galax.pos.get("p2")" or "galax.pos.get("p2").debris" or "galax.pos.get("p2").debris.titanium". I'm thinking it may be a problem parsing the JSON.

Comment: It doesn't look like a valid json array string though, Can you post the full json string?

Comment: @yorkw the json string is valid for sure. I validated so many times lol. NotACleverMan Here you have the logcat: http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagen-error-7582740.html

Comment: I see "pos" in the code but not in the JSON string.

Comment: @dldnh fixed! you were right! You must answer my question 'officially' so that I can mark your answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see "pos" in the code but not in the JSON string. official answer. :-)